# MySQL: Get products having all attributes listed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some problems to get this query works as I expect.

I have three tables: `products`, `product_attributes` and `attributes`.
The relation is obvious (A product can have multiple attributes)

```
products
---------
id

product_attributes
------------------
product_id
attribute_id

attributes
----------
id
name
```

What I want to achieve is to get those products that has a given list of attributes, BUT omit those products that only has a partial list of the desired attributes.
For example, having these products and attributes:

- Shoe 1 [blue,boy]
- Shoe 2 [blue,girl]
- Shoe 3 [red,boy]
- Shoe 4 [red,girl]

A query asking for those products with [blue,boy] would retrieve only `Shoe 1`.
A query asking for those products with [blue] would not return anything.

Since now I was working with this query:

```
SELECT p.*, pa.attribute_id
FROM products AS p 
LEFT JOIN product_attributes AS pa ON(pa.product_id=p.id)
WHERE 
pa.attribute_id IN(' . implode(',', $attr_ids) . ')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING count(pa.attribute_id)=' . count($attr_ids)
```

This fails when just an attribute is given because it will return any product having that attribute.

Comment: Also, your WHERE clause renders your (LEFT) OUTER JOIN as an INNER one!

Comment: What does it means @Strawberry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- PHP (or any other languaje) parts are hardcoded here!!!!

SELECT p.*, hma.howmuchattr
-- howmuchattr is needed by HAVING clause, 
-- you can omit elsewhere (by surrounding SELECT or by programming languaje)

FROM products AS p 
LEFT JOIN product_attributes AS pa ON pa.product_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, count(*) as howmuchattr
    FROM product_attributes 
    GROUP BY product_id
) as hma on p.id = hma.product_id

WHERE 
pa.attribute_id IN 
(1,3)                    -- this cames from PHP (or any other languaje). Can be (1) for the other case
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING count(*) = howmuchattr;
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff1b2/13) here
see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24813880/443685)

Comment: Still gives me those products that has ANY of the attributes listed. I need products having only the attributes listed.

Comment: Hi again, I've faced a scenario where this still does not work. Trying to list "Shoe 2 [blue,violet]" (notice violet does not exists in my example dataset) it still loads a result as howmuchattr is 2 and it loads any "Shoe 2" that has two attributes, being one of them "blue".

Comment: I don't understud your inquiry. Shoe2 is definded in two records of product_attributes as [blue,girl]. How it is also defined as "Shoe 2 [blue,violet]"??? please setup an sqlfiddle and paste it link here. I am glad to help.

Comment: It seems sqlfiddle is not working right now (it takes forever to build schema), I'll try to post it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from any other issues, this query...

```
  SELECT p.*
       , pa.attribute_id
    FROM products p 
    LEFT 
-- OUTER (this keyword is optional in MySQL)
    JOIN product_attributes pa 
      ON pa.product_id = p.id
   WHERE pa.attribute_id IN('$attr_ids')
   GROUP 
      BY p.id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = $cnt;
```

... is logically identical to...

```
  SELECT p.*
       , pa.attribute_id
    FROM products p 
-- INNER (this keyword is also optional in MySQL)
    JOIN product_attributes pa 
      ON pa.product_id = p.id
   WHERE pa.attribute_id IN('$attr_ids')
   GROUP 
      BY p.id
  HAVING COUNT(pa.attribute_id) = $cnt;
```

In order to maintain the utility of the OUTER JOIN consider rewriting as follows...

```
  SELECT p.*
       , pa.attribute_id
    FROM products p 
    LEFT 
    JOIN product_attributes pa 
      ON pa.product_id = p.id
     AND pa.attribute_id IN('$attr_ids')
   GROUP 
      BY p.id
  HAVING COUNT(pa.attribute_id) = $cnt;
```